# PHP Extract Parts Of A URL Based On A Pattern

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url-routing

I'd like to be able to extract certain aspects of a URL, based on a pattern:

`http://www.mywebsite.com/{type}-for-sale-in-{district}/{id?}`

In this case, I need to be able to extract the parts within the curly braces above. This was inspired by Laravel routing, and will always be the pattern.

Initially I was thinking of somehow doing this with .htaccess, but I'd rather just process the values right on the page with PHP.

Comment: Did someone seriously vote to close my question within 5 seconds of posting it? Unbelievable.

Comment: The code I've tried previously doesn't work at all, so it's pointless. I honestly have no idea how to do this and just need help from the community to get me going in the right direction. And the question isn't obvious?

Comment: Some culprit there, who vote negative and we can't see it who is doing that

Comment: can't you split the data with - then part[0] is for type

Comment: .htaccess or `mod_rewrite` can definitely handle this URL

Comment: I just got here and I'm voting to close. Question is too broad, states arbitrary constraints without explanation or justification and does not exhibit any attempt to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

```
$uri = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
if(preg_match("#^(?P<type>\w+)-for-sale-in-(?P<district>\w+)(/(?P<id>\d+))?$#i",
              $uri, $matches)
{
  var_dump($matches['type']);
  var_dump($matches['district']);
  if(isset($matches['id']))
    var_dump($matches['id']);
}
```

[Demo here](https://eval.in/487255).

Comment: I like the use of preg :)

Comment: It's a pattern. It's what regular expressions are for  :)